# Django Rest Framework custom schema for view in viewset

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have an API built using Django and Django REST Framework. I have a model that returns some JSON that is built that doesn't correspond to a typical Django model. So the auto-documentation feature that seems to utilize knowledge about Django models doesn't work for some of my views.

In particular, I have a viewset that returns some typical API views (like a list of objects), and some views that return some of my custom objects. I'd like to build documentation for these custom objects, but I am not sure how to override the schema for a particular endpoint within a viewset. How can I override the schema generated for a single view in a DRF viewset?

[DRF seems to provide this functionality for views](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#manual-schema-specification), but I want to do the same for Viewsets.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I didn't. I just ended up building out custom documentation on my own.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Custom documentation as in completely separate documentation or just this part using coreapi/schema in DRF?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, after a lot of try-fail-retry, I finally got it to work - you lose some of the auto(magical) introspection, like the `id` path parameter and the description taken from the docstring, but I still thing it's worth it:

```
custom_schema = ManualSchema(
    fields=[
        coreapi.Field(
            "id",
            required=True,
            location="path",
            schema=coreschema.String(
                title="ID",
                description="Foobar ID.",
            )
        ),
        coreapi.Field(
            "foobar",
            location="query",
            schema=coreschema.String(
                title="Foobar",
                description="Foobar?",
            )
        ),
    ],
    description="Foobar!",
)


class FoobarViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):

    @action(methods=["get"], detail=True, schema=custom_schema)
    def foobar(self, request, id=None):
        ...
```

Comment: How do you do this for built in views like list, get, etc.. ?

Comment: You can re-define them, decorate them, and return exactly what they would with `super()`

Comment: Thats the thing, you cant decorate them with `action` ... seems to be limiting. Do you have an example to share?

Comment: Oh, I see your point. No sorry, I don't have any other ideas right now.